# Removing Sliding Widgets plugin create include errors

Tags: php, wordpress

So I updated my plugins, then I uninstalled my Sliding Widgets plugin and now I get the following warning messages in the admin panel and above the header of my site:

```
Warning: include(shortcodes.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/functions.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'shortcodes.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php5.5') in /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/functions.php on line 2
```

Any ideas on how I could rectify this?

***UPDATE:***
My first few lines in my functions.php were:

```
<?php
    include('shortcodes.php');
    // theme textdomain - must be loaded before redux
    load_theme_textdomain( 'shopkeeper', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

But I commented the `include('shortcode.php');` to see what would happen.  It made the warnings go from above the header of my site, which is great, however now on my login page I only get the following warning appearing on the page and can no longer log in:

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/functions.php:1) in /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196
```

What my functions.php looks like currently:

```
<?php
        // include('shortcodes.php');
        // theme textdomain - must be loaded before redux
        load_theme_textdomain( 'shopkeeper', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );
```

Comment: Could you share the first lines of your _functions.php_ file ?

Comment: `<?php
include('shortcodes.php');
// theme textdomain - must be loaded before redux
load_theme_textdomain( 'shopkeeper', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );`

Comment: Well it seems that this _shortcodes.php_ file is missing in your theme directory. It shouldn't have been deleted by the uninstallation of the plugin, so it probably come from something else. Could you check that _shortcode.php_ exists in your theme folder?

Comment: ye i have and it doesn't, it's in my wp-include folder though, should i move it?

Comment: The _shortcodes.php_ in _wp-include_ folder is one of the Wordpress core file, so no you shouldn't move it or you'll break your website. The _shortcodes.php_ from your theme folder should be something else - usually it's a file containing custom shortcodes added by your theme. I suggest you to comment the `include('shortcodes.php');` line on top of  your _functions.php_ and see if it break anything.

Comment: when i delete that line, it comes up with the same error message

Comment: It shouldn't. It's the exact same message, that say the error is on line 2?

Comment: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-content/themes/shopkeeper/functions.php:1) in /homepages/14/d442309306/htdocs/app572581842/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196`

So no errors appearing up at the top of the site anymore, however i get this whenever I try to access my login page.

Comment: Just to be sure, you deleted `include('shortcodes.php');`, not the `<?php` tag right? Your _functions.php_ still begins with `<?php` (without any blank line / white space before it)?

Comment: yes i just turned it into a comment, the include shortcode.php part that is...

Comment: ... So there is still `<?php` at the start of your functions.php, **without any space or blank line before it**?

Comment: yes, there's no white space or anything before it

Comment: Ok, because the message you get is saying that you're sending data to output (could be an PHP error - but if you have only this error message it shouldn't be except if you have weird `error_reporting` settings - or more probably some space or blank line) at the first line of your _functions.php_ file. I suggest you to edit your question and add the first lines of your _functions.php_ as they are right now.

Comment: edited! Thanks for your help, even though we still haven't got to the bottom of this.

Comment: All right so what you need to check now: - check that there isn't anything at the end of your _functions.php_ (if there is a closing tag, you can remove it) - check that _functions.php_ is in UTF-8 - not ANSI or whatever

Comment: yep all done, even copy and pasted into a new file ensured it was in utf-8 encoding before saving, replaced the functions.php with the new functions.php file and still got the same error.  It doesn't make any sense, because line 1 is just `<?php`, nothing before it and there is no space or blank lines at the end of the file either.

Comment: Mmmh just noticed that it could come from _pluggable.php_ so it may be a plugin. I suggest you to disable your plugins one by one in order to identify which one is causing this.

Comment: Ye I would, however I can't log in to remove the plugins...

Comment: You can manually disable a plugin by changing his folder name. So in _wp-content/plugins/_ rename for example _my-plugin_ for _my-plugin_.

Comment: so that didn't work either, just the same message everytime.

Comment: When you edit your _functions.php_ file in Notepad++, the enconding is UTF-8 or UTF-8 w/o BOM?

Comment: ahh... i have been a fool